# File permissions for mounted volumes in image processing pipelines?

Tags: linux, docker, sudo

We're using docker to containerize some image processing pipelines to make sharing them with collaborators easier.

The current method we're using is to mount an "inputs" directory (which contains an image. i.e. a single jpg) and an "outputs" directory (which contains the processed data. i.e. maybe a segmentation of the input image). The problem we're having is we run docker with sudo, and after the processing is complete, the files in the outputs directory have root permissions.

Is there a standard or preferred way to set the files in mounted volumes to have the permissions of the calling user?

Comment: Do you mount the directories within the docker image, or externally on the host and pass them in with the -v option?

Comment: @Matt We pass them in with the `-v` option.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the --user flag in `docker run`

e.g.

`docker run --user $UID [other flags...] image [cmd]`

Alternatively the following might work (untested)

In Dockerfile

`ENTRYPOINT "su $USERID -c"`

Followed by:  `

`docker run -e USERID=$UID [other flags...] image [cmd]`

Comment: I'll look into this!

Comment: I ened up using `--user $(id -u):$(id -g)`  which I'm happy with

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the user in your Dockerfile so that when the container is started it uses 'tomcat' for example.

```
# example
USER tomcat
```

Comment: This won't work because different used can call the script to run on their computer. And the permissions should be the user that calls the script. Imagine you're using the docker to simply copy a file. If you mount an "inputs" directory with the file and mount the "outputs", if the docker copies the file, the file in  the "outputs" directory will have root permissions instead of the user that called the docker.

Comment: @Justin - the process inside the docker container will try to run as the tomcat user.  But if the tomcat user doesn't exist, I'm not sure what happens, maybe it will remain as root.  Better to use UserID's in Dockerfile's.  In any case, it doesn't do what you're wanting.